# iptables drop packets by IP protocol type

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

Is it possible to have `iptables` rules to drop packets by *IP protocol type* as described in [http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ipv4/ipv4_packet_structure.htm]? (ICMP is 1, TCP is 6 and UDP is 17, but what if I want to block an arbitrary type, say 47 for GRE)

Is there anything better than `-m string` then specify an explicit offset to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

`-p`: It may also take a value specified in the `/etc/protocols` file. Since it looks as if `gre` is already specified, this pretty much solves it.